# Getting parent class field value instead of child field which supposed to override parent's

Tags: java, oop

While trying to get child class field getting parent field. In this example, when new `DarkRoom` is being created the int zero is passed to `DarkRoom` constructor. It supposed to assign zero int to `thisRoomNumber` field. The next step- creating `Tenant` and passing one object `DarkRoom` which we initialized. For some reason in `Semaphore` class the `nextRoom` has field `thisRoomNumber` which inherited from `Room` and has value `96` despite the fact **we assigned zero**. What is missing? Why I cannot get `0` from `nextRoom.thisRoomNumber` The design is quite complex, maybe there is a bit simpler solution?

```
public abstract class Room {
public int thisRoomNumber = 96;
}
```

Main method:

```
 public class TestCase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Room s[] = new Room[1];
            {    
               s[0] = new DarkRoom(0, s);
                 }
        new Tenant("Joe", s[0], s);
        }
    }
```

DarkRoom class:

```
public class DarkRoom extends Room {

private Room thisRoomType = this;
public int thisRoomNumber;
private Room[] rooms;   
private  Semaphore semaphore= new Semaphore();
@Override
void leave(Tenant t) {
    semaphore.release(thisRoomType, rooms, t);
}
public int thisRoomNumber;

public DarkRoom(int i, Room[] s) {

        this.thisRoomNumber = i;
        this.rooms = s;
    }
}
```

Semaphore class:

```
public class Semaphore {
public synchronized void release( Room thisRoom,  Room[] allRooms, Tenant t) {
Room nextRoom;

        while(j < allRooms.length &&

            allRooms[j].negativeCounter == 0 &&

            thisRoom.getClass().equals(allRooms[j].getClass())){ 

            j++;
        }
nextRoom = allRooms[j];
System.out.println(nextRoom.getClass().getName() +"' "+nextRoom.thisRoomNumber);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hiding the field `thisRoomNumber` by declaring it in the subclass as well. Remove the declaration of it in the sub class (`DarkRoom`).

Comment: Will I get zero from hidden filed *thisRoomNumber* inside (and only inside) class *DarkRoom*?

Comment: Exactly, if you have it defined twice like this. I think you meant to only have it defined once, in the parent class.

Answer (score 2):

Fields are not polymorphic in Java. Only methods are. Do what every decent book suggests, and never use public fields. Use a getter instead, and override the getter in the subclass. Fields can't be overridden.